# Find Coordinates of object without openCv

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, matlab, coordinates

Hi everyone I need little help in finding coordinates of an object in an image. I want to write an algorithm that find the coordinates of the bug inside the picture (having chickens in it) but **WITHOUT** using openCv library. Is there any way to write such algorithm without using openCv. I am unable to get a clue that how it can be done without any library.
[refrence image is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5YEo.jpg)

Comment: First you need to be clear about the constraints on the bug... could it be rotated - if so, you need a rotation-invariant algorithm... could it be a different size - if so, you need a scale-invariant algorithm... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

At first, there are some vision libraries for Python besides of OpenCV, some might contain function for pattern recognition.

For own implementation you need some way to access pixels of image, so you definitely have to use some library.

In the simplest case (slow) go through all pixels, comparing rectangles of large images with small one (pattern).

To make things faster, you can implement and apply [image correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_correlation_and_tracking) - requires using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform). Maximum of correlation result might correspond to the shift of pattern against large image. This method is used in OpenCV `matchTemplate` function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have access to the image of the bug you search. If you want to find the object in the image without using OpenCV then your algorithm should be simple. The simplest algorithm would be comparing the object with the image at each location. I cropped the bug from the input image and searched it in the image as in the following tested code. The code found the object at the correct location. The following code finds the grayscale patch in the grayscale image.

```
    img=imread('w5YEo.jpg'); img=rgb2gray(img); szImg=size(img);
    bug=imread('bug.jpg'); bug=rgb2gray(bug); szBug=size(bug); bug_coord=0;
    for i1=1:szImg(1,1)-szBug(1,1)  %scan image
      for j1=1:szImg(1,2)-szBug(1,2)  %scan image
       %Measure image correlation using subtraction
       patch=img(i1:i1+szBug(1,1)-1,j1:j1+szBug(1,2)-1);
       img_diff=patch-bug;
       if abs(sum(sum(img_diff)))<50000 %Threshold determined empirically
         bug_coord=[i1 j1];
       end
      end
    end
```

One can apply downsampling to the image to increase the speed of the code above.
Another improvement can be achieved by finding the edges in the image. That way, the correlation between the images can be calculated faster. There are many edge detection algorithms developed so far: Sobel, Roberts, Canny and others.